# MATLAB undo a command

Tags: matlab, undo

I am currently developing a basic image processing application on MATLAB. I have to implement **undo to previous state** feature. I searched net there is **uiundo** but it only undos GUI actions. Is there a simple command to undo. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have plenty of memory to spare, you could store all of your program states in a structure and then push this structure into a [circular buffer](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/05/08/implementing-a-simple-circular-buffer/). The number of elements in the buffer would determine the number of levels of undo.

Comment: +1: good idea. Another one is to save everything to disk after each operation, though this might be an overkill :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that you would have to implement your own multi-level (or one-level) undo by using the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

This would require you to wrap your operations into objects that contain the logic to perform the action and to restore the state. No silver bullet, hard work needed.

Answer (score 2):

General undo will be complicated, but if you are only interested in saving the state of MATLAB variables and returning to a saved state, this might be one possible solution:

save_state.m:

```
SavedStateFolder = '/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/';
save([ SavedStateFolder, 'saved_state_', sprintf('%06d', (size(dir(SavedStateFolder), 1) - 1)) ]); 
fprintf('state saved in saved_state_%s.mat\n', sprintf('%06d', (size(dir(SavedStateFolder), 1) - 2)));
```

undo_index.m:

```
function undo_index()
SavedStateFolder = '/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/';
FilesStruct = dir(SavedStateFolder);
LastSavedStateIndex = size(FilesStruct, 1) - 2;
if (LastSavedStateIndex < 1)
    fprintf('No saved states available.\n');
else    
    fprintf('Index of last saved state is %06d\n', LastSavedStateIndex);
end
return
```

undo.m:

```
SavedStateFolder = '/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/';
load([ SavedStateFolder, 'saved_state_', sprintf('%06d', input('Enter saved state index ')) ]);
```

Then you can use `save_state` to save the state of MATLAB variables or you can even prefix all your commands with `save_state;` if you want to keep track of all changes. When you want to return to a previous state of variables, you can run `undo_index` to find out the index of last saved state and then you can run `undo` and input the index given by `undo_index`, or alternatively any smaller positive integer to return to an earlier state of variables. The first saved state file will be named `saved_state_000001.mat`, then `saved_state_000002.mat` and so on... Note that `save_state` saves everything to disk, so using SSD or RAM disk might be a good idea if you want to try this in a loop with a lot of data. Note also that the previous content of variable called `SavedStateFolder` is lost when you run `save_state` or `undo`. To avoid this, you can replace all instances of `SavedStateFolder` in `save.state.m` and `undo.m` with hard-coded folder names, for example:

save_state.m:

```
save([ '/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/', 'saved_state_', sprintf('%06d', (size(dir('/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/'), 1) - 1)) ]); 
fprintf('state saved in saved_state_%s.mat\n', sprintf('%06d', (size(dir('/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/'), 1) - 2)));
```

undo.m:

```
load([ '/home/user/matlab_saved_states_folder/', 'saved_state_', sprintf('%06d', input('Enter saved state index ')) ]);
```

Note also that `save_state`, `undo_index` and `undo` assume that in `SavedStateFolder` there are no other files except `.`, `..` and `saved_state_*.mat` files. Also the number of `saved_state_*.mat` files and the running index to be saved is found out this way, so if you delete some previous `saved_state_*.mat` files without eg. creating equal number of empty files to replace them, the counts don't match and `save_state` might save the state on top of an already existing saved state file.